# What is the most efficient way to store emails in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to store emails in database to use in a php application. The rest of the application is stored in mysql. Is mysql the best way and in what format to store. Or is there another way that would be better?

Comment: If all your other data is stored in a database, why not store the email there too?

Comment: Jam it into a `LONGTEXT` columm, perhaps?

Comment: What is the preferred language? Usually you would use MySQL table column charset type to support the language i.e.: email_address varchar(255) character set utf8 or email_address varchar(255) character set ascii. If you do not specify the charset it will get inherited from the original DB collation settings.

Comment: An email address is just a text string. No different from username, first name or what ever.. it's just text. Save it in the same way you're saving other text strings.

Comment: Do you mean you want to store email addresses, or actual emails?

Answer (score 1):

This was amended from 320 to 256 chars. See below:

There is a length limit on email addresses.  That limit is a maximum of 64 characters (octets)
in the "local part" (before the "@") and a maximum of 255 characters
(octets) in the domain part (after the "@") for a total length of 320
characters. However, there is a restriction in RFC 2821 on the length of an
address in MAIL and RCPT commands of 256 characters.  Since addresses
that do not fit in those fields are not normally useful, the upper
limit on address lengths should normally be considered to be 256.

Source: http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=3696